# jpa hibernate cascade.merge with one-to-many relationship inserts instead of merge

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I have this kind of entity.

```
@Entity
public class CartItem {
    String cItemId;
}

@Entity
public class Cart {

    @OneToMany(cascade={MERGE, PERSIST}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=EAGER)
    Set<CartItem> cartItems;
}
```

I perform an update outside a session bean, effectively on a detached entity. Thus:

```
cart
  .getCartItems()
  .stream()
  .forEach(cItem -> process(cItem));

//Then persist the entity, using a transactional stateless bean.
cartService.persist(cart);
```

The problem is that hibernate decides that the cart items are new, and performs an insert, rather than an update on the cascades and hence i get database exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1469166285629-1a6205be-315b-4bc2-8390-9c7b19ade518-1484522387119' for key 'PRIMARY'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

The duplicate entry happens on the join table `Cart_CartItem` table, since hibernate does not perform a merge but an insert, yet the CartItem is already referenced on the join table.

This was not happening, it suddenly started, and i am wondering what can be wrong.

My scenarios:

- Wildfly 10 (wildfly hibernate)
- java8

Comment: why to update `cartItem` manually if there is `cascade.MERGE, PERSIST` is already there in mapping?

Comment: updated to remove the confusion on the ```update``` method. That method simply processes cart_items, it does not update to db

Comment: Not getting the issue. may be you can try with `@Transaction(REQUIRES_NEW)`